# Call a page from a window in wpf. Page should be called in different window not in the same window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF window called 'Mainwindow.xaml'.
I want to navigate a WPF page named 'devicemaipping.xaml'.

Currently I am able to replace the window content from the page as below-

```
DeviceMapping devMapping = new DeviceMapping();
this.Content = devMapping;
```

I want to call the page in a different Pane or window, so my main window should remain open.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create another `Window` and show it? You could do something like this:

```
var w = new Window();
w.Content = devMapping;
w.Show();
```

You could even show it modally like this:

```
w.ShowDialog();
```